# jQuery.keypress: Instant text processing

Tags: jquery, input

I need to replace the default keypress-event, for the additional (instant) transformation of the text as you type. Trying this:

```
field.keypress(function(e){
    field.val(function(i, val){
        return val.toUpperCase();
    });
    return false;
});
```

But input is not filled completely, it is understandable why. But how to?)

Please, don't suggest "text-transform", toUpperCase() is just an example. ))

Comment: how to make an immediate replacement of all uppercase letters (for example) when you type?

Comment: @Stefan Have you read the last line? The OP clearly requested to not suggest `text-transform`.

Answer (score 3):

The `keypress` event is fires before the text field has actually modified.

You should bind the function to the `keyup` event.

This `keyup` event only fires once per keystroke, though. If you press the a key, the `keypress` event will fire before each character populates the text field. The `keyup` event is only fired *after* the key has been released. So, if you hold <kbd>e</kbd> for 10 seconds, the input field will contain lowercase `e` characters, until you lift your finger.